# Does only the character selected at the beginning get a long intro?

Tags: octopath-traveler

I started with the knight character and he had an intro about an hour long with quests etc... Soon after I found another character and she joined the party after I played a very short backstory (no combat or quests and still level 1).

This made me wonder does only your starting character get a long intro or is it just dependent on character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time a new character joins your party, you get to play through their initial "tutorial", The Prologue, followed by their Chapter 1 story. As you progress through the game, you can play through each character's story equally.

There is no difference between choosing a certain character as your initial character, or in the order of having new characters join your party, aside from having multiple members in your party to play through the story with.

Comment: So you get to do chapter 1 of the new character along (in a party) with the rest of your characters?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Difficulty will be adjusted to reflect the fact you are technically 'overpowered'.